# Amazon SP-API endpoint to get Billing address by order ID

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-mws, amazon-selling-partner-api

I'm using Amazon Selling Partner API to import orders in my application.
I'm using orders/v0/orders to get the orders list and foreach order returned I call

1. /orders/v0/orders/{orderId}/address to get shipping address
2. /orders/v0/orders/{orderId}/orderItems to get items in order
3. /orders/v0/orders/{orderId}/buyerInfo to get buyerEmail and buyerName

Now, the last thing I need is to get the eventual billing address.

I search in SP-API documentation but I didn't find anything useful.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible. This was asked regarding MWS and the response was "why" given that Amazon handle all billing. I suspect SP-API is similar.

https://sellercentral.amazon.com/forums/t/retrieving-buyers-billing-address/124948